# Repetitive if statements reduction

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

What are the ways of reducing code quantity in a method that contains schematic conditional statements?

What would be a good practice of placing such code. Should it be in a different method/class?

Example code in Java. It contains one scheme repeated twice:

```
if (calculation[i].equals("*")) {
    if (stack.canDoOperation()) {
        times();
    } else {
        operationFailed = true;
    }
} else if (calculation[i].equals("+")) {
    if (stack.canDoOperation()) {
        sum();
    } else {
        operationFailed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch statement. Use exceptions rather than booleans for exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a helper method, wrapping the given operation method into the commonly required checks. You could also put a `try/catch` in there, in case the operation can fail.

```
private boolean tryOperation(Runnable operation) {
    if (stack.canDoOperation()) {
        operation.run();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
if (calculation[i].equals("*")) {
    operationFailed = ! tryOperation(this::times);
} else if (calculation[i].equals("+")) {
    operationFailed = ! tryOperation(this::sum);
}
```

Or, with Java 8, you can put the method references to those operations into a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Runnable> operations = new HashMap<>();
operations.put("*", this::times);
operations.put("+", this::sum);
...

Runnable operation = operations.get(calculation[i]);
if (operation != null && stack.canDoOperation()) {
    operation.run();
} else {
    operationFailed = true;
}
```

You can also combine the two approaches:

```
operationFailed = ! tryOperation(operations.get(calculation[i]);
```

Comment: Addendum: This assumes that all the operation methods have no-parameter and of type void; if they return something, you'd have to swap `Runnable` with `Supplier<X>`.

Comment: How does exactly "this::times" work as implementation of Runnable? Please explain so that I could understand better why did you do it this way, and not - for example - by building another class.

Comment: @Prusio In Java 8, `Runnable` is a `@FunctionalInterface`, so any `lambda` or method reference that takes no parameters and returns nothing -- i.e. has the same interface as the only method of `Runnable`, `run`, can stand in as a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example of how you can utilize repetitive statements. For more clarity you can extract `stack.canDoOperation()` to variable if it doesn't break your logic. Also you can consider moving it to assertion in beginning of the method and than put `calculation[i]` into switch statement.

```
if (calculation[i].equals("*") && stack.canDoOperation()) {
        times();
    }
} else if (calculation[i].equals("+")  && stack.canDoOperation()) {
        sum();
    }
} else {
        operationFailed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement into an if and maybe in a more logical way : check if you can do an operation, and if so find which one :

```
if (stack.canDoOperation()) {
    switch(calculation[i]){
        case "*": times(); break;
        case "+": sum();   break;
} else {
    operationFailed = true;
}
```

---

You can also give the value of operationFailed into the if statement :

1. `operationFailed = !stack.canDoOperation()` will be done first (if you cannot  do an operation, operationFailed will true;
2. the value of `!operationFailed` (`!!stack.canDoOperation()` = `stack.canDoOperation()`) will be used in the if test

```
if (!(operationFailed = !stack.canDoOperation())) {
    switch(calculation[i]){
        case "*": times(); break;
        case "+": sum();   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7, it's possible to `switch` over `String`s.

```
switch (calculation[i]) {
    case "*":
        times();
        break;
    case "+":
        sum();
        break;
}
```

Furthermore, for each calculation type, you are repeating the `canDoOperation` check. It's better that you bubble up this check:

```
if (stack.canDoOperation()) {
    operationFailed = true;
}
else {
    switch ... // Your switch statement
}
```

---

I suggest you move these operations to a separate method:

```
/**
 * Performs the specified operation.
 * @param The operation to perform.
 * @return True if the operation was succeeded, false otherwise.
 */
boolean performOperation(String operation) {
    if (!stack.canDoOperation()) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (operation) {
        case "*":
            times();
            break;
        case "+":
            sum();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, without knowing the rest of your code, it's unclear whether this is a good solution.